# Printing char array with null character in the middle in C

Tags: c, null, char

I have noticed that when you try to print a null character in C, nothing will get printed.

```
printf("trying to print null\n");
printf("%c", '\0');
```

However, I am trying to print the characters in the following array one by one, up to the sixth character which is the null character.

```
char s[] = "Hello\0Bye";
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

I was expecting "Hello" to be printed, as since the sixth character is null nothing will be printed. However my output was: "HelloB".
It seems like printf skipped the null character and just went to the next character. I am not sure why the output is "HelloB" instead of "Hello".

Any insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: This applies for determing the length of the array i guess.

Comment: Which character is really at index `6`? Draw out the string on a squared paper, one character per square, and count if you're unsure.

Comment: It certainly does not skip the character. Try piping your programs output to `sed 's/\x0/\n/g'`, see what gets printed.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be 'i < 6' not 'i < 7'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction `'\0'` is commonly used to represent the null character. Here

```
printf("%c", '\0');
```

it prints nothing.

And in the decalaration of `s`

```
char s[] = "Hello\0Bye";
```

when you print like

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%c", s[i]); 
}
```

`printf()` prints upto `0<7(h)`, `1<7(e)`..`5<7(nothing on console)`,`6<7(B)` iterations only and `6th` charactar is `B` hence its prints `HelloB`.

*I was expecting "Hello" to be printed ?* For that you should rotate loop until `\0` encountered. For e.g

```
for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) { /* rotate upto \0 not 7 or random no of times */ 
   printf("%c", s[i]); 
}
```

Or even you no need to check `s[i] != '\0'`

```
for(i = 0; s[i]; i++) { /* loop terminates automatically when \0 encounters */ 
     printf("%c", s[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below two options
1. `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`
2.Iterate through each character and print it.

Answer (score 0):

`int i; for(i=0; i<7; i++)` generates 7, not 6 iterations.
Printing `\0` generates no pixels on the console (character 6) and then the 7th character (`B` follows).